# JDBC get available Schemes list before connecting

Tags: jdbc

I need to get the list of the schemes in a database before I connect to it ,for the connection I use

```
connection=DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:port:scheme",username,password);
```

how to get the schemes before the above line?

Comment: I don't see how you could get information from a database without connecting to the database.

Comment: @JBNizet If I remember correct in SQL developer in the add new connection window after you feel the nessesary (ip,port...) info you can hit get schemes and it will download the schemes list for you to select to what you need to connect.I dont ofcourse mean without connecting to the db,I mean how to get the schemes list without first connecting to a particulate scheme.

Comment: If you google for "oracle list database schemas", you'll probably get the answer you want. Note the proper term: schema, and not scheme.

Comment: @JBNizet ,yea but the problem is how do I connect to the db(so that I can execute a query) without providing a scheme.

Comment: What you call "scheme" is what Oracle calls an SID: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC#Thin_driver. The default **schema** (with a A, not a E), AFAIK, depends on the username used to connect. If you connect with a user having the right permissions, you'll be able to list all the schemas.